# Inserting a link

Tags: html, css

How can I turn the facebook font awesome icon into a link? Whenever I insert a link it pushes the icon out of the frame of the picture. I would like to put other social media icons beside the facebook icon aswell but at the moment I am just trying to solve the problem of getting the icon to link to facebook.

CSS

```
.polaroid-images a {
 background: white;
 display: inline;
 float: left;
 margin: 0 15px 70px;
 padding: 10px 10px 25px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
 box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
 -webkit-transition: all .15s linear;
 -moz-transition: all .15s linear;
 transition: all .15s linear;
 z-index: 0;
 position: relative;
}

.polaroid-images a,
 :after {
 color: #333;
 font-size: 20px;
 content: attr(title);
 position: relative;
 top: 15px;
}

.polaroid-images img {
  display: block;
  width: inherit;
}

.polaroid-images a,
 i:nth-child(3n) {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-24deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(-24deg);
 transform: rotate(-24deg);
}

.polaroid-images a:hover {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
 transform: rotate(0deg);
 -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
 -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
 transform: scale(1.2);
 z-index: 10;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
 box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
}

.polaroid-images i {
 position: relative;
 font-size: 1em;
 top: 15px;
 margin-right: .5em;
 color: #3b5998;
}
```

HTML

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-
awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="polaroid-images">
  <a href="" title="Alex"><img height="200" 
   src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" alt="Island" 
  title="Alex" class=fishes /><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-3x"></i></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add some relevant code.

Comment: Where is your HTML ?

Comment: It wasn't spaced properly so it got cut off, I have just edited it.

Answer (score 0):

So, as of right now you have a link that is wrapping your entire card. You should probably remove this unless you want the whole card to link to Facebook. Here's what I would do:

```css
.polaroid-images div {
 background: white;
 display: inline;
 float: left;
 margin: 0 15px 70px;
 padding: 10px 10px 25px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
 box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
 -webkit-transition: all .15s linear;
 -moz-transition: all .15s linear;
 transition: all .15s linear;
 z-index: 0;
 position: relative;
}

.polaroid-images div,
 :after {
 color: #333;
 font-size: 20px;
 content: attr(title);
 position: relative;
 top: 15px;
}

.polaroid-images img {
  display: block;
  width: inherit;
}

.polaroid-images div,
 i:nth-child(3n) {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-24deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(-24deg);
 transform: rotate(-24deg);
}

.polaroid-images div:hover {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
 transform: rotate(0deg);
 -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
 -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
 transform: scale(1.2);
 z-index: 10;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
 box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
}

.polaroid-images i {
 position: relative;
 font-size: 1em;
 top: 15px;
 margin-right: .5em;
 color: #3b5998;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-
awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="polaroid-images">
  <div title="Alex">
    <img height="200" 
   src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" alt="Island" 
  title="Alex" class=fishes />
    
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-3x"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Essentially, I just removed the `a` tag from the entire block and only wrapped it around four FB icon. Then I changed your container to a div and changed the style accordingly.

Hope this helps!